# Use of undeclared type 'Response' error

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

Recently i've updated my xcode to version 8.0 and Alamofire 4.0. After that I'm getting `Use of undeclared type 'Response'` for this code :

```
func getDate(completion: (Response<AnyObject,NSError>) -> Void){
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://www.example.ir/api/utiliti/example" ,parameters:nil)
        .responseJSON{ response in
            completion(response)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I posted an issue on alamofire github and got the answer!

[Use of undeclared type 'Response' error](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1535)

use this code

```
public enum Response {
    case Failed(error : String)
    case Success(data : Any)
}

func getDate(completion: @escaping (Response) -> Void){
    Alamofire.request("www.example.com/api", method: .get ,parameters:nil)
            .responseJSON{ response in
                switch response.result{
                case .failure(let error):
                case .success(let value):
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. problem magically solved when you post issue on github?

Comment: What did you change Response to?

Comment: I've defined an enum `public enum Response { case Failed(error : String) case Success(data : Any) }`  and changed `completion: (Response<AnyObject,NSError>) -> Void` to `completion: @escaping (Response) -> Void` @MatthewDrill